# Eclipse C/C++ thick white vertical line on the left

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse IDE with C/C++ plugin. When editing C/C++ code, the editor shows this thick white vertical line on the left that i would like to turn off. I searched through plugin and general setting but i couldn't find the option to turn it off.

[This figure](http://db.tt/IdcshGx) shows the line that i wish to disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the color theme you are using for the editor. Is the line present when you use other themes?

Comment: That is true. I am using Eclipse Color Theme plugin. On this figure the popular Oblivion theme is being used. It seems that this thick white line is present when i use any of the dark themes, but on the white themes the line is thin and dark. On the plugin homepage (eclipsecolorthemes.org) the Oblivion theme is shown without this white line.

Comment: I just installed the CDT and tested the dark themes and the line is thin like it should be. But I'm using Linux, so it meight be a problem on the windows version.

Comment: Thanks for testing :) I'm also on linux, but using version 3.5 Galileo. At least i know where the problem lies.

Comment: I'm with the latest Indigo and don't have to problem, perhaps you could test the latest version and see if it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to get rid of it and ended up here. I tried to right click on the line and select 
Folding->Enable Folding. 
Deselected that and the line is gone!
Not sure on how to change it to a different colour though if you want Folding enabled.